# Cannot use split in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use `split` in Ruby, but I'm getting this error:

> `importantFuncs': private method `split' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

I have tried adding `require String` and `require string`, but neither are working.

```
require 'socket'
class IRC
    def initialize(ip, port)
        @s = TCPSocket.new(ip, port)
        print 'Now connected to ip ', ip, ' at port ', port, "\n"
    end
    def getPacket()
        line = @s.gets
        puts line
    end
    def closeConnection()
        @s.close
    end
    def sendPacket(packet)
        @s.write(packet)
    end
    def importantFuncs(nick)
        sendPacket("NICK #{nick}")
        z = getPacket
        @m = z.split(':')
        sendPacket("NICK #{nick}")
    end
    #def joinChannel(
end
ip = '127.0.0.1'
port = '6667'
i = IRC.new(ip, port)
i.importantFuncs('test')
i.getPacket
```

Comment: Paste the code that doesn't work here rather than making us go look at it. Consider posting just a minimally-failing example.

Answer (score 6):

Your `getPacket` method returns `nil` instead of string `line`.

That's because in Ruby every method returns a value by default. And this value will be the value of the last statement in the method. Also you can use `return` statement to redefine this behavior as in other programming languages, but it is not often used in Ruby.

```
def getPacket()
  line = @s.gets
  puts line # returns nil, and whole method returns nil too
end
```

So, you should make `@s.gets` the last expression in this method

```
def getPacket()
  @s.gets
end
```

or add `line` to the end if you really need to print this `line`

```
def getPacket()
  line = @s.gets
  puts line
  line
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The "That's because in ruby methods return the return value of the last expression in it (if you didn't use return explicitly)" seems a bit confusing. Could anyone elaborate on it a bit more?

Comment: `puts` always returns `nil`, so your getPacket method returns nil.

Comment: @user1432856, I'm sorry for confusing, I have edited my answer and I hope wrote more clearly

Answer (score 3):

Your `getPacket` method returns `nil`. You probably want it to return `line` or something else. Just add `return line` to the end of `getPacket`.